# Share raw resource via WhatsApp "Failed to send, please try again"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, share

i want to share an audio when a button is hold, i save the mp3 to the external storage and then share it but i have an error "failed to send, please try again" (something like that, the original is in spanish). what can i do?

the code:

```
b0.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.teagachas);

            try
            {
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "lastshared.mp3"));
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
                {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/lastshared.mp3"));
            share.setType("audio/*");
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "compartiendo \"" + b0.getText() + "\""));
            return true;

        }
    });
```

PD: the code is in the onCreate method

Comment: You need to change `catch (Exception e) {}` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. If it prints an error, post the full stack trace here. Having an empty catch block like that is like driving without watching the road. You're just completely ignoring whether or not there's an error while writing the file.

Comment: E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.   That is the stack trace, sorry about the error, this is my first app haha, thanks